# In yii2 trying to view and update records without id value in the url during CRUD

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to yii2, so in yii2 basic how to view and update records without id value in the url during CRUD

**Code:**

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want access to a view or an update form for an instance ..you need the id ... explain better with a sample too what you need .

Comment: If you are concerned of users manipulating the app by changing ids. You can encode it in the url.

Comment: When I click on the view button on the index page, getting id value in the url to view the page. I want without id value in the url and view page. same for update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view. Create an update button

```
echo 
Html::beginForm(['/model/update'], 'post',['id' => 'update-form']) .
'<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$model->id.'">
 <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById(\'update-form\').submit(); 
return false;">Update</a>'. 
Html::endForm();
```

Then in your controller

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    if ( Yii::$app->request->post() ) {

        if ( isset (Yii::$app->request->post()['Model']['id']) ) {
            $id = Yii::$app->request->post()['Model']['id'];
        } else {
            $id = Yii::$app->request->post()['id'];
        }

        $model = $this->findModel($id);
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: but how to change this controller to hide id value
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}

Comment: echo 
Html::beginForm(['/model/view'], 'post',['id' => 'view-form']) .
'<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$model->id.'">
 <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById(\'view-form\').submit(); 
return false;">View</a>'. 
Html::endForm();
public function actionView()
{
    if ( Yii::$app->request->post() ) {

        if ( isset (Yii::$app->request->post()['Model']['id']) ) {
            $id = Yii::$app->request->post()['id'];
        }
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
    
}

Comment: Thanks Ryan White  i executed this code but in that i can view the first row only. That is if click on any row's view i am getting the first row value only, so can i do in that.

Answer (score 0):

We can access view and update page without id value in the Url by creating Modal to view and update button.